# PHP float with 2 decimal places: .00

Tags: php

When I do this typecasting:

```
(float) '0.00';
```

I get `0`. How do I get `0.00` and still have the data type as a float?

Comment: `0.00` is not a valid float see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Answer (score 143, accepted):

A float doesn't have `0` or `0.00` : those are different string *representations* of the internal ([IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)) binary format but the float is the same.

If you want to express your float as "0.00", you need to format it in a string, using [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) :

```
$numberAsString = number_format($numberAsFloat, 2);
```

Comment: I didn't want a string. Wanted a float. But since it's not valid to have 0.00 apparently, I'll have to make do with "0.00" or 0.

Comment: we can't keep float data type after formatting. So not valid answer as per the question.

Comment: @SeniorPHPDeveloper The question is ill-formed. The format of a floating point number is a binary sequence, which has no concept of decimal digits at all. Saying "how do I format a floating point number as decimal but still keep the data format" is like saying "how do I translate this to French but still keep it as English".

Comment: @IMSoP, yes correct. I explained the same

Comment: @SeniorPHPDeveloper Then your comment from 2020 makes no sense. This answer is as "valid" as it's possible to be: it says you can't do that as a float, but here is how to do it as a string.

Comment: @IMSoP, please understand the question first and rethink about it.

Comment: @SeniorPHPDeveloper I'm honestly confused what you're saying. Your comment from 2020 says that this is "not a valid answer", implying that you think a different answer *would* be valid; but you seem to agree that the requirement to "keep data type as float" is impossible; so the *only* possible answer is to talk about string representations, which is what this answer does. So what point are you trying to make, exactly?

Comment: @Denys Séguret , is there is a way to return a decimal value that is not in string? Instead of "0.00" it will return 0.00 Thank you

Answer (score 10):

As far as i know there is no solution for PHP to fix this. All other (above and below) answers given in this thread are nonsense.

The number_format function returns a string as result as written in PHP.net's own specification.

Functions like floatval/doubleval do return integers if you give as value 3.00 .

If you do typejuggling then you will get an integer as result.

If you use round() then you will get an integer as result.

The only possible solution that i can think of is using your database for type conversion to float. MySQL for example:

```
SELECT CAST('3.00' AS DECIMAL) AS realFloatValue;
```

Execute this using an abstraction layer which returns floats instead of strings and there you go.

### JSON output modification

If you are looking for a solution to fix your JSON output to hold 2 decimals then you can probably use post-formatting like in the code below:

```
// PHP AJAX Controller

// some code here

// transform to json and then convert string to float with 2 decimals
$output = array('x' => 'y', 'price' => '0.00');
$json = json_encode($output);
$json = str_replace('"price":"'.$output['price'].'"', '"price":'.$output['price'].'', $json);

// output to browser / client
print $json;
exit();
```

Returns to client/browser:

```
{"x":"y","price":0.00}
```

Comment: Thanks for point to json, If you sure just work with numbers and no contain any `"` chars, so after use `number_format` and json encoding, just can use it: `$json = str_replace('"', '', $json);`

Comment: But then your key may not contain spaces, else your output will not validate. Some people do ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but it is you who is speaking nonsense. You are absolutely right that `number_format` returns a string; and a string is what you need any time you want to see a number. If you looked at the binary representation of an integer or floating point number it would not look like "2", or "2.0", or "2.00", or anything else; those are *human-readable* representations of the number.

Comment: As for JSON (which isn't mentioned in the question), just use [the JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION option documented here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php). Again, this is about how to *represent* the number, not what type it *is*.

Answer (score 6):

0.00 is actually 0. If you need to have the 0.00 when you echo, simply use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) this way:

```
number_format($number, 2);
```

Comment: It will make data type string when you convert it to JSON

Answer (score 6):

You can show float numbers

- with a certain number of decimals
- with a certain format (localised)

i.e.

```
$myNonFormatedFloat = 5678.9

$myGermanNumber = number_format($myNonFormatedFloat, 2, ',', '.'); // -> 5.678,90

$myAngloSaxonianNumber = number_format($myNonFormatedFloat, 2, '.', ','); // -> 5,678.90
```

Note that, the

1st argument is the float number you would like to format

2nd argument is the number of decimals

3rd argument is the character used to visually separate the decimals

4th argument is the character used to visually separate thousands

Answer (score 2):

Use the `number_format()` function to change how a number is displayed. It will return a `string`, the type of the original variable is unaffected.

Comment: Hi @Bart Friederichs is there a wat to return as decimal data type instead of a string ? Thank you

Comment: @natsumiyu PHP does not have a decimal data type, so no there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$nom="5695.5";
number_format((float)($nom), 2, '.', ','); // -> 5,695.50

$nom="5695.5215";
number_format((float)($nom), 2, '.', ','); // -> 5,695.52

$nom="5695.12";
number_format((float)($nom), 0, '.', ','); // -> 5,695
```

> //use round()

```
$nom="5695.12";
number_format((float)round($nom), 2, '.', ','); // -> 5,695.00

$nom="5695.52";
number_format((float)round($nom), 2, '.', ','); // -> 5,696.00
```

Comment: Not workable with 1.000 or 10.000,12 (other countries currency format)

Comment: echo number_format((float)round(10.000,12), 2, '.', ','); // -> 10.00;

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,it will work for you

```
number_format(0.00, 2)
```

Comment: but in PHP it can't maintain data type

Answer (score 0):

A number of comments on this page have missed the fundamental point that the question is ill-formed. Floating point is a *binary* representation, designed for efficient calculations; it fundamentally has no notion of decimal digits of any sort.

So asking this:

> How do I get "0.00" instead of "0" and still have the data type as a float?

Is like asking this:

> How do I get "deux" instead of "zwei" and still have the language as English?

Whether you specify the input as "2", or "2.0", or "2.000000000", if you ask for a floating point value, what will be stored in memory is this (in IEEE 754 double-precision):

> 0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

If you convert to an integer, the value stored in memory is this (assuming a 64-bit system):

> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010

(Note that "integer" in this context is not just a synonym for "whole number", it is a specific data type, with its own rules for how values should be represented in memory.)

By contrast, the string "2" would look like this:

> 00110010

And the string "2.00" would look like this:

> 00110010001011100011000000110000

(In a PHP program, there would actually be additional information in memory, such as an indicator of the type, but that's not really relevant here.)

---

So, the question can *only* be answered by rephrasing it as a *conversion*: given the *input* of a floating point number, how do I *choose a string representation* which has a fixed number of decimals.

As others have pointed out, the answer to that is to use [number_format](https://php.net/number_format).

---

The question doesn't mention JSON, but several comments do, so I will also point out that PHP's [json_encode](https://php.net/json_encode) function has an option `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION`, which will format a floating point number that happens to be a whole number with a trailing ".0", for instance:

```
$example = ['int' => 2, 'float' => 2.0];
echo json_encode($example);
# => {"int":2,"float":2}
echo json_encode($example, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION);
# => {"int":2,"float":2.0}
```

Again, note that this is a *string representation* of the value.

Answer (score -1):

You  can use round function

```
round("10.221",2);
```

Will return 10.22

Comment: what is the difference between 10.00 and 10

Comment: my use case is to use 2 decimal places to display prices consistently, but I still want it to be a float so I can perform calculations on it. The original question specifically wants the .00 to be shown.

Comment: but in PHP it can't maintain data type

Comment: it's working fine. thanks jewelhuq.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `floatval()`

[floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

Comment: Does not limit to two decimals.

Answer (score -2):

**try this**

```
$result = number_format($FloatNumber, 2);
```

Comment: but in PHP it can't maintain data type

Comment: Hi @SeniorPHPDeveloper is there a way to maintain the data type? Instead of returning string ? Because using ```number_format()``` it returns string. If using ```floatval()``` if the value is 0 or 123 it will not add .00

Answer (score -3):

When we format any float value, that means we are changing its data type to string.  So when we apply the formatting on any amount/float value then it will set with all possible notations like dot, comma, etc. For example

```
(float)0.00 => (string)'0.00',
(float)10000.56 => (string) '10,000.56'
(float)5000000.20=> (string) '5,000,000.20'
```

So, logically it's not possible to keep the float datatype after formatting.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this simple function.
    **number_format ()**

```
    $num = 2214.56;

    // default english notation
    $english_format = number_format($num);
    // 2,215

    // French notation
    $format_francais = number_format($num, 2, ',', ' ');
    // 2 214,56

    $num1 = 2234.5688;

   // English notation with thousands separator
    $english_format_number = number_format($num1,2);
    // 2,234.57

    // english notation without thousands separator
    $english_format_number2 = number_format($num1, 2, '.', '');
    // 2234.57
```

Comment: but in PHP it can't maintain data type