# PHP - how to get consistent output for API of values - floats with specific number of decimal places

Tags: php

My API request currently returns JSON in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "date":"2016-08-11",
    "voltage":0.1,
    "current":0.01,
    "power":0,
    "energy": null,
  }
]
```

I'm trying to ensure consistency of data output by forcing the voltage, current and power values to be three decimal places, type float. I've tried using `number_format()` but the output are type strings, which I do not want. Is there a way of doing this, i.e. outputting `0` as a float `0.000` rather than staying an integer? Also, when no values are present I need to convert null into 0.000, is that possible without casting to strings?

The question [PHP float with 2 decimal places: .00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706519/php-float-with-2-decimal-places-00) doesn't explain (in layman's terms) why this is not possible in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP float with 2 decimal places: .00](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706519/php-float-with-2-decimal-places-00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo floatval(number_format('0.001', 3)); // output: float 0.001
```

But unfortunately strings containing `'0.000'` or `null` after type casting will produce `0`.

```
echo (float)number_format('0.000', 3); // output: 0
echo floatval(number_format('0.000', 3)); // output: 0
echo floatval(number_format(null, 3)); // output: 0
```

"...bytes with value 0 (“NUL bytes”) are allowed anywhere in the string (however, a few functions, said in this manual not to be “binary safe”, may hand off the strings to libraries that **ignore data after a NUL byte**.)" [Details of the String Type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

You may handle output at the presentation layer instead.

Comment: This will still return `1` and not `1.000` as @OP requested.